# flutter Geocoder : Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, google-places-api

*Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received*

Hi Please assist, I am using Geocoder on my flutter app to get latitude and longitude from google places,

Below is the code I use to get latitude and longitude

```
onPressed: () async {
 FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextButtonFocusNode);
 Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                                context: context,
                                apiKey:"MY_API_KEY",
                                language: 'en',
                                mode: Mode.fullscreen,
                                components: [
                                  Component(Component.country, 'za'),
                                ]);

if (p != null) {
   areasOfOperationChanged = true;
   //error started when i added this line
   var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

   AreaOfOperation aoo = AreaOfOperation();
   aoo.description = p.description;
   aoo.placeId = p.placeId;

   aoo.lattitude = address.first.coordinates.latitude.toString();
   aoo.longitude = address.first.coordinates.longitude.toString();

   aoo.profileNo = widget.profile.profileNo;

   if (widget.profile.areasOfOperation == null) {
         widget.profile.areasOfOperation = [aoo];
       } 
   else { widget.profile.areasOfOperation.add(aoo);
        }
     }
   }
```

My problem is that when this block runs it throws the following error.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received
E/flutter (31015): #0      IOClient.send
package:http/src/io_client.dart:62
E/flutter (31015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31015): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
package:http/src/base_client.dart:91
E/flutter (31015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31015): #2      GoogleMapsPlaces.autocomplete
package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.dart:169
E/flutter (31015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31015): #3      PlacesAutocompleteState.doSearch
package:flutter_google_places/src/flutter_google_places.dart:421
E/flutter (31015): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31015):
```

When I add a try-catch block around this code, the exception is not handled.

The Geolocator version I am using is **geocoder: ^0.2.1**

Flutter version:

```
flutter --version
Flutter 2.0.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8962f6dc68 (4 months ago) • 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
Engine • revision 5d8bf811b3
Tools • Dart 2.12.1
```

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, since I can see that it is triggered by `onPressed`?
Also, have you tried running a Debug version and putting few breakpoints and then digging deeper also into the Geocoder, probably the exception is thrown but also handled somewhere inside?

Comment: Hi, yes I was running the app on the debug mode, the unhandled exception breakpoint initially hits the io_client.dart file(IOClient class) in the method  Future<IOStreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {